# Which version of Drools to use with Activiti 5.16.1?

Tags: drools, activiti

Which version of Drools to use with Activiti 5.16.1 ? The Activiti 5.16.1 comes with BusinessRuleTask, which by default uses Drool. They must have built and tested it with specific version of Drool, but it's not mentioned in the user guide.

I'm reluctant to use the latest version of Drools (6.1) knowing there was big split between JBoss and Activiti at some point in the past.

Thanks in advance,
Raka

Comment: You can check version information from [here](http://mvnrepository.com). For Activiti 5.16.1 Drools version is 5.5.0.Final. Details [here](http://mvnrepository.com/artifact/org.activiti/activiti-engine/5.16.1).

Answer (score 0):

Oh, found it. Just have to check their pom.xml: https://github.com/Activiti/Activiti/blob/master/pom.xml

It's 5.5.0.Final

[image]